# Convert PHP preg_match to javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-match, match

can somebody help me converting this

```
preg_match('/^(.*?)[#,\.0]+(.*?)$/',$patterns[0],$matches)
```

into Javascript equivalent?
I tried doing

```
matches = patterns[0].match('/^(.*?)[#,\.0]+(.*?)$/')
```

but this results in null...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the quotes from the regex

```
matches = patterns[0].match(/^(.*?)[#,\.0]+(.*?)$/);
```